# Recursion in helper methods (Java)

Tags: java, recursion, helpermethods

I am practicing recursion and using a recursive helper method. In my helper method, an error appears saying that

> The method someMethod(K) in the type Tree is not applicable for the arguments (K, List, int).

However, I do not want to use the `someMethod(K k)` method as I am trying to use the `someMethod(K k, List<K> L, int n)` helper method. How do I make Eclipse "know" that I'm trying to use the other method?

Here's what I have thus far:

```
public List<K> someMethod(K k) {
    List<K> L=new LinkedList<K>();
    if (lookup(k) != null) {
        return someMethod(k, L, 0);
    }
    return L;
}

private List<K> someMethod(K k, List<K> L, int n) {
    if (this.k.compareTo(k) == 0) {
        L.add(this.k);
        return list;
    }
    if (this.k.compareTo(k) < 0) {
        right.someMethod(k, L, n); //error here
        L.add(this.k);
    }
    if (this.k.compareTo(k) > 0) {
        left.someMethod(k, L, n); //error here
        L.add(this.k);
    }
}
```

---

Edit:
declarations for left and right:

```
private Tree<K, V> left, right;
```

Comment: It this only an annotation from Eclipse or is the program actually not compiling?

Comment: Well, when I try to run the project it says that there are errors so I guess the program is actually not compiling because of that. I have no other errors.

Comment: Please show us the declarations of `left` and `right`.

Comment: Also, recursive helper methods that call themselves with the exact same parameters they're given have an annoying tendency to stack-overflow.

Comment: What's a `Tree`?  Is that the class that includes `someMethod`?  I think you need to post the whole thing.

Comment: I do not get an error on the lines you indicate, assuming everything else is declared suitably.  You have probably done something else wrong in the rest of your code, but I can't see it.  Also, as @Turing85 pointed out, your method needs to return something, but the presence or absence of the return doesn't affect whether I get any errors or warnings on those lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First problem I see in the second method is that you are only returning something in the case when the statement

```
if (this.k.compareTo(k) == 0)
```

is true.

The compiler should give you an error because your method is declared to return `List<K>`

```
private List<K> someMethod(K k, List<K> L, int n)
```

To solve this, you should return something either in each `if` statement, or at the bottom of your method. Based on your logic, you want to return an error value when no matches satisfying the above `if` statement are found. Thus, for example, you could return `null` by putting this statement at the bottom of your method:

```
return null;
```

Or, if you don't want to deal with `null` values, return an empty list:

```
return new ArrayList<K>();
```

If you make this change your code compiles fine on my machine.

*Here is an [**Ideone example**](http://ideone.com/1FpQKY) that compiles fine with the change I suggested.*

Furthermore, as @ajb mentioned in the comments, you aren't really taking care of the base case for your recursion.

Meaning, you are not changing the arguments:

```
K k, List<K> L, int n
```

of your recursive method when you pass them through recursion and thus will end up in an "infinite" recursion causing [**`StackOverFlowError`**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StackOverflowError.html) in the case where no elements satisfy the condition

```
if(this.k.compareTo(k) == 0) {
    L.add(this.k);
    return list;  // this returns from recursion but nothing else
}
```

You should define some sort of a base case that will stop the recursion no matter if you find matches or not.

Answer (score 0):

Your helper-method is missing a final return-statement, which is probably messing up the syntax-check, ending in this strange error-message.

```
private List<K> someMethod(K k, List<K> L, int n) {
    if (this.k.compareTo(k) == 0) {
        L.add(this.k);
        return list;
    }
    if (this.k.compareTo(k) < 0) {
        right.someMethod(k, L, n); //error here
        L.add(this.k);
    }
    if (this.k.compareTo(k) > 0) {
        left.someMethod(k, L, n); //error here
        L.add(this.k);
    }
    return L; // change here, errors should be gone now
}
```

Comment: No.  Missing `return` statements are not syntax errors.  They are errors, but they will not be caught by the part of the compiler that cares about the syntax.

Comment: @ajb, yes they are. The compiler requires us to always return something if the return type isn't `void`.

Comment: Please reread what I said carefully.  They are errors, but they are not **syntax errors**.  This sort of error will **not** confuse the compiler into putting an error on a different line.

Comment: One could argue about the kind of error. I think ajb is right, because the Parser performs return-statement checks on the AST and therefore it might be a semantical error. Nevertheless, this is/was the problem and it is fixed now =)

Comment: @ajb, sorry for not reading carefully. I see what you meant now.